# How can I confirm whether Circuit Breaking (via DestinationRule) is at work or not for external service (ServiceEntry & VirtualService)

Tags: istio

### Summary of Problem

I'm trying to impose Circuit Breaker parameters for an external endpoint outside of my mesh, hosted somewhere else. However, the parameters I have set doesn't seem to be imposed because I am still getting successful HTTP 200 responses, when I expect it to start failing with HTTP 503.

Tools versions are:

- Istio-1.2.4
- Kubernetes: v1.10.11
- Docker Dekstop Version 2.0.0.3

Notable config:

- `global.outboundTrafficPolicy.mode` is `REGISTRY_ONLY`.
- Within Mesh is `mTLS`. External traffic policy, TLS is `DISABLED`

### Related Resources

ServiceEntry

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  hosts:
    - external-service.sample.com
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  exportTo:
    - "*"
  ports:
    - number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
  resolution: DNS
```

VirtualService

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: external-service-vs
spec:
  hosts:
    - external-service.sample.com
  http:
    - timeout: 200ms
      retries:
        attempts: 1
        perTryTimeout: 200ms
      route:
        - destination:
            host: external-service.sample.com
            port:
              number: 80
```

DestinationRule

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: external-service-dr
spec:
  host: external-service.sample.com
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: DISABLE
    connectionPool:
      tcp:
        maxConnections: 1
        connectTimeout: 200ms
      http:
        http2MaxRequests: 1
        http1MaxPendingRequests: 1
        maxRequestsPerConnection: 1
        maxRetries: 1
        idleTimeout: 200ms
    outlierDetection:
      consecutiveErrors: 1
      interval: 1s
      baseEjectionTime: 10s
      maxEjectionPercent: 100
```

### Testing

I have an application inside the mesh injected with an Envoy Proxy. The app basically just run load concurrent for HTTP1.1 GET external-service.sample.com/endpoint.

I adjust the number of concurrent users in the App (1 to 10) and requests per second per user (1 to 20).

I was expecting for the response to start failing with the ramp up. But that's not the case. I get success throughout.

### Key Asks

1. If you see something very glaring, please point it out.
2. I already checked logs and /stats from my Envoy Proxy (outgoing request and response). What other istio logs do I need to check to understand more whether the request was subjected and evaluated by istio to the destinationrule or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not really addressed the issue directly on this.
But, I have done the whole setup from the start with a clean slate all over again from setting up istio. And after that it was already throwing the expected HTTP 503.

It was rather challenging than necessary to know the state of the circuit breakers. There was supposed to be a [ticket](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/4762) logged, but it seems development for such feature is not yet on the horizon.

Nevertheless, when verifying, I did take a look on some telemetry metrics to understand the circuit breaker state. I think this way could be better because I only want to know whether the circuit is close or open at a moment and not analyze from multiple input data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the statistic data gathered by Istio [Mixer](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/policy-and-telemetry/mixer-overview/) from nested [Envoy](https://istio.io/docs/ops/telemetry/envoy-stats/) instances, you might consider fetching Circuit Breaker events from Envoy [Access logs](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log#format-rules).

Since Access logging [enabled](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/telemetry/logs/access-log/#enable-envoy-s-access-logging) across Istio mesh plane, you can extract the relevant Circuit Breaker log entries, distinguished by specific response [flags](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/observability/access_log.html?highlight=response_flags#command-operators):

> UO: Upstream overflow (circuit breaking) in addition to 503 response
>   code.

And fetched up record from container's envoy proxy access logs, i.e:

```
[2019-09-18T09:49:56.716Z] "GET /headers HTTP/1.1" 503 UO "-" "-" 0 81 0 - "-"
```